# How do I output the location using gps on Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to output the location into a textview.
I have used the locationManager.toString(), but it would only give me the output android.location.LocationManager@44ee7718.
I would like to output the location like Los Angeles, CA 90501.

The code for LocationManager:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //conversion
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bp = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(bp);
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lon = location.getLongitude();
    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = null;
        try{
            addresses = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    Address address = addresses.get(0);
    final String ad = address.getAddressLine(0);
    //ends here
```

The code for the button:

```
Red.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.putExtra("sms_body", ad);
            intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code

```
try {
                // Get the location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                    bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
                    Location location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
                    double lat = location.getLatitude();
                    double lon = location.getLongitude();
                    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
                    List<Address> lstAdd = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
                    Address ad = lstAdd.get(0);
                    String str = ad.getAddressLine(0);
                Toast tst = Toast.makeText(this, "Your current location is " + str,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                tst.show();
} catch (Exception e) {
                Toast tst = Toast.makeText(this,"Please check your gps settings",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                tst.show();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hmm.. thank you for your answer, but am i suppose to make try and catch for gc.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1)?

Comment: i dont think i should use try and catch but it would give me an error without it...

Comment: thank you so much....
but what i really tried to do was to output it through an sms and i used an intent for the sms and its not getting the toast... do you know how to make that toast usable in a button function? or the string works too

Comment: What do you mean by toast usable in button function? You can use dialog to display your text and accompany with required button

Comment: i have updated my code and this is what i have so far... it is not giving me any error but when i run the emulator, the app will not run and tells me that the application has stopped unexpectedly...

Comment: i actually got it to work... but just having a trouble with outputting it into the sms body

Comment: Happy to know that I could be there to help you. Well, **trouble with outputting it into sms body** is out of scope of this question. Please post another question on this site with proper explanation where you have stuck and error you get with logcat. I am sure there will be many like me to help you

Comment: Worth noting that getLastKnownLocation does not always work; it may return null if the device doesn't currently know a location (which can happen quite easily).

Answer (score 0):

Call appropriate Location methods (getLatitude(), getLongitude())

Read this,  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

Also for converting to human readable names, you need to use GeoCoding

Read this, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

Also, http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/geocoding.html