# Not display location but display longitude & latitude

Tags: android

I am trying to display current loaction and longitude, latitude. I can easily fetch longitude & latitude but not able to display current location.
I am displaying my code below.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{ 
LocationManager locationManager ;
     String provider;
     Context context;

     @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     }
}




    if(provider!=null && !provider.equals("")){

        // Get the location from the given provider 
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 1, this);


        if(location!=null)
        {
            onLocationChanged(location);


             //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location can't be retrieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Provider Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
    // Getting reference to TextView tv_longitude
    TextView tvLongitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_longitude);

    // Getting reference to TextView tv_latitude
    TextView tvLatitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_latitude);

    // Setting Current Longitude
    tvLongitude.setText("Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());

    // Setting Current Latitude
    tvLatitude.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() );


// From here i want to get the location, as i pass current longitude &
```

latitude here. It passes null
 in address means here it executes else instead of if.

```
    try {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);

         if (addresses != null ) {
             Address address = addresses.get(0);
             // sending back first address line and locality
            String result = address.getAddressLine(0) + ", " + address.getLocality();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"result",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
    if (addresses.size() > 0) {
        String address = "";
        for (int index = 0; index < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
            address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) + " ";

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.v("AddressTag", address);
    }

    else
    {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}   

}




@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}
```

Comment: Code? Post it here only

Comment: public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
 
 LocationManager locationManager ;
 String provider;
 Context context;
 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: Edit the question with code. This way, its not readable

Comment: public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
 
 LocationManager locationManager ;
 String provider;
 Context context;
 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);        
        
        
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

Comment: Post the complete code example in your question. What you've posted so far doesn't say much...

Comment: Check out this [link for reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16371874/2345913)

Comment: i had posted my code. Plz check it..

Comment: @CRUSADER my code is almost similar ti it. I pass location in on location changed & from there i am fetching location. But it's not display location

Comment: @user2368731: What kind of lat/long are you passing? There's no guarantee that you always get back an address, as per documentation: *"Returns null or empty list if no matches were found or there is no backend service available."*.

Comment: @CRUSADER i used that code but in toast it gives me error plz chk your gps setting. What settings i have to change for gps. Plz help me i m new to android

Answer (score 0):

If List is empty/null I bet that you do not have a Geocode backend service to do the actual lookups. The [documentation says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) that "The Geocoder class requires a backend service that is not included in the core android framework. The Geocoder query methods will return an empty list if there no backend service in the platform."

If you want to use the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) for reverse lookup you need to [include it in your project](https://developers.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/installing) and [obtain a Maps API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key). "In previous versions of the SDK, the com.google.android.maps package was included in the standard Android library and system image. In the Android 1.5 SDK, that is not the case. The Android 1.5 library and system image do not include the Maps external library (com.google.android.maps). However, the Maps external library is available as part of the Google APIs add-on for the Android SDK"

Update: Since you mention that the GeoCoder.isPresent() returns true it means that a backend service exists and the problem lies elsewhere. I had a look at the Google Maps API FAQ and it mentions that lat/long to address lookups [doesn't work everywhere](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_countries). Have a look at [this spreadsheet](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mapcoverage_filtered.html) and set the Geocode filter to No. Is the country you're doing lookups for listed?

Comment: i am not able to undrstand what exactly you are saying bcz i m new to android. Plz give me the code line what i have to add to perfrm this task..

Comment: The solution to your problem is in the links in my answer. Why don't you read the linked documentation and try to add Google Maps API to  your project and then updated your question with any problems that you encounter. Simply asking for someone else to write your code is not good.

Comment: yes.actually  in pc emulator it show address is zero, but when i check it on samsung tab it shows exception in tab.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `Geocoder` is working on your device? This is what they specify in the description of [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html).
`The Geocoder class requires a backend service that is not included in the core android framework. The Geocoder query methods will return an empty list if there no backend service in the platform. Use the isPresent() method to determine whether a Geocoder implementation exists.`
This is only working on a few devices, if you really want to get the address you should use the google api. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: I only get latitude & longitude & now with the help of reverse geocoder i want to obtain current location. Plz let me know where i am mistaking in code. I am new to android

Comment: The geocoder doesn't work on all of the devices, it only works on a few devices. You should first do `Geocoder.isPresent()` to see if the geocoder is available on your device. If it isn't you can't use it and you should use the google services to get the address

Comment: i am testing it on emulator & it shows geocoder is not present. now what should i do..?

Comment: just now i check it on samsung tab..on tab it shows in case of geocoder but inside try catch it calls catch block just after this line of code addresses = geo.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);

Comment: plz help me i m trying to do this since last three days

Comment: If geocoder.isPresent() returns true I really have no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: Hold on, do you catch and Exception of some kind? Which exception?

Comment: what is the exception it is throwing? please post it. If the `Geocoder` isn't working you can always use the google geocoding services, you send the latitude and longitude and you will get the list of addresses

Comment: @ britzl Sir i print toast in tr catch..is gives exception just after the code  addresses = geo.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);

Comment: @ bodgan How can i use google geocoding service. I didnt get any example of this type from internet or from this group. pLz let me know how can i do this. I m new to android

Comment: @ bodgan in pc emulator is show address is zero, but when i check it on samsung tab it shows exception in tab.

Comment: Please edit your question and put the exception that is thrown by `code addresses = geo.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);`. About the google geocoding service, all you need to do is read [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding). You will make a call to the server and after that parse the json or xml answer(json is easier)

Answer (score 0):

have you given these permissions in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />    
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

And is your device connected to internet?

check with Geocoder.isPresent() whether geocoder is present or not

Comment: i already added permission in the manifest but geocoder is not present.when i m checking geocoder.isPresent() it returns false. Now what should i do..?

Comment: geocoder is present but it gives error in addresses = geo.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);

Comment: plz help me i m trying to do this since last three days

Comment: Have you got the api key from google? it should be added to the manifest <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="YOUR KEY"/>